# I'm Trying to Create an Image Object with a Byte Array as Its Source. What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: image, .net-3.5, nullreferenceexception, memorystream, bitmapimage

I'm trying to create an image object with a byte array as its source. What am I doing wrong?

An exception is thrown when I try to initialize the image object with an array of bytes as source data. The exception is shown in my code, below.

```
public class MyClass
{
    publuc System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage InstanceImage { get; set; }

    public void GetImage()
    {
        // Retrieves a list of custom "Item" objects that contain byte arrays.
        // ScvClnt is our service client. The PollQueue method is designed to return information to us.
        lstQueue = SvcClnt.PollQueue(1);

        // This condition always evaluates as True, since we requested exactly 1 "Item" from the service client.
        if (lstQueue.Count == 1)
        {
            // lstQueue[0].InstanceImage is a byte array containing the data from an image file.
            // I have confirmed that it is a valid TIFF image file, by writing it to disk and opening it in MSPaint.
            if (lstQueue[0].InstanceImage != null)
            {
                // This condition is also True, since the image is just under 3KB.
                if (lstQueue[0].InstanceImage.Length > 0)
                {
                    this.InstanceImage = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                    this.InstanceImage.BeginInit();
                    this.InstanceImage.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream(lstQueue[0].InstanceImage);
                    InstanceImage.EndInit();
                    // The call to EndInit throws a NullReferenceException.
                    // {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
                    // I have confirmed that this.InstanceImage and this.InstanceImage.StreamSource are not null at this point.
                    // They are successfully assigned in the lines of code above.
                } else InstanceImage = null;
            } else InstanceImage = null;
        } else InstanceImage = null;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what on Earth could possibly be going wrong.
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/97489102-b43e-41f6-8429-f0da6778abed) uses this example as a solution.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(abyteArray0))
{
    image.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}

//The field image should be of type System.Windows.Controls.Image.
```

I used the BitmapFrame.Create method that takes only the stream as a parameter, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'm following what you're trying to do with your class at first glance, but to address the original question, give this a shot:

```
    public static Image ConvertByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

Comment: I believe that this is a solution for .NET 2.0 or the like. I am working in .NET 3.5 using WPF. Therefore I'm not using System.Drawing